Best way to generate anyon worldline diagrams
In the literature on anyons, I often see nice worldline diagrams like this: 
Does anyone know of an efficient way of generating such diagrams?

comment cause i'm too lazy to write down a full answer, but i think you're looking for the braids package.

Something like this?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{braids, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % to place the bottom ellipse "behind"
                             % the braid

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw the braid
  \pic[braid/.cd,every strand/.style={blue,line width=2mm},width=10mm, gap=0.2,
  crossing height=10mm,
  border height=20mm,
  ] (b) % name it
  {braid={s_2^{-1} s_1 s_2 s_2 s_1}};
  
% add circles at the ends
  \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
  \foreach \j in {s,e}
  \node[fill=blue, ellipse, minimum width=6mm] at (b-\i-\j) {};

  % top ellipse
  \draw[top color=white, bottom color=red, fill opacity=0.5]
  (b.north) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);

  % bottom ellipse
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \draw[top color=white, bottom color=red, fill opacity=0.5]
  (b.south) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\end{scope}

% time arrow
\draw[-Latex, ultra thick] ([shift=({-1,1})]b.south west)--node[sloped,above]{time}
([shift=({-1,-1})]b.north west);
  
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}



Wonderful, thank you!
